# How to make alias open files

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I created a 'npp' alias, which is simply running notepad++ through wine:

```
wine '/media/USER/.../Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'
```

How can i make this alias open (for example) *.txt file when im double clicking it ?

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Interesting question. But it might be a better fit on http://askubuntu.com, you might even find a similar question has been asked and answered

Comment: I think i remember having read in the wine doc, that you just have to pass an option (something like -i$file) at the end of the command. So, if you have an alias, say `notepad_alias`, then you would do something like `notepad_alias -i$file`

Comment: This works for me in bash: `alias npp='WINEPREFIX="/home/username/.wine" wine C:\\Tools\\Notepad\\Notepad++.exe'` and I can after that use `npp /tmp/somefile`. Do you mean the bash alias mechanism? Where do you doubleclick?

Comment: I want this alias to be in menu "Open with.."